# How do C pointers correlate to C# in this example?

Tags: c#, c

I am currently trying to port a library from C over to C#, most of it has went smoothly so far but I've hit a roadblock when it comes to converting struct pointers from C.

Here is the C code that I am trying to convert:

```
//Queue.c File
struct queue
{
    struct queue* next;
    void* e;
};

struct queue* create_queue_node(void* element)
{
    struct queue* tmp = malloc_node();
    tmp->e = element;
    return tmp;
}

void append_queue_node(struct queue* node, struct queue* after) // adds node next to after
{
    node->next = after->next;
    after->next = node;
}


//Allocator.c File
#define QUEUE_CHUNK 65536
#define MOVE_CHUNK 65536

struct move* alloc_moves = 0; // allocated moves
int last_move = MOVE_CHUNK;
struct move freed_moves;

struct queue* alloc_nodes = 0; // allocated nodes 
int last_node = QUEUE_CHUNK;
struct queue freed_nodes;

void inicialize_allocator()
{
    freed_moves.parent = 0;
    freed_nodes.next = 0;
}

struct queue* malloc_node()
{
    if (last_node < QUEUE_CHUNK)
        return &alloc_nodes[last_node++];
    else
    {
        alloc_nodes = malloc(sizeof(struct queue)*QUEUE_CHUNK);
        last_node = 1;
        return alloc_nodes;
    }
}
```

Now I understand that C# count a Class as a reference type so `(queue* node)` in C is the same as `(Queue node)` in C# (if I understand correctly). So here is the C# code I have so far:

```
//Queue.cs File
public class Queue
    {
        public Queue next;
        public IntPtr e;

        public Queue createQueueNode(IntPtr element)
        {
            Queue tmp = mallocNode();
            tmp.e = element;
            return tmp;
        }

        public void appendQueueNode(Queue node, Queue after)
        {
            node.next = after.next;
            after.next = node;
        }

        public Queue removeQueueNode(Queue before)
        {
            Queue tmp = before.next;
            before.next = before.next.next;
            return tmp;
        }

        public bool isQueueEmpty(Queue head)
        {
            return head.next == null;
        }
    }

//Allocator.cs File
public static class Allocator
{
    public static Move allocMoves = null;
    public static int lastMove = Global.MOVECHUNK;
    public static Move freedMoves = null;

    public static Queue allocNodes = null;
    public static int lastNode = Global.QUEUECHUNK;
    public static Queue freedNodes = null;

    public static void initializeAllocator()
    {
        freedMoves.parent = null;
        freedNodes.next = null;
    }

    public static Queue mallocNode()
    {
        if(lastNode < Global.QUEUECHUNK)
        {
            return //?
        }
        else
        {
            allocNodes = new //?
            lastNode = 1;
            return allocNodes;
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure how the allocation of the allocNodes variable should be done though, or it's usage on the return line. How should something like this be implemented in C#?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? If you want idiomatic C# can't you just use `Queue<T>`? (**not** `Queue<IntPtr>`, use something meaningful instead)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski My intention was to port it almost directly over to C# to make sure it works and then change parts of the code to use more .NET features instead of the self-built ones in C.

Comment: Bad idea. Throw away your old C code and use directly modern C# features and libraries. Porting low level C to C# is pretty pointless.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Unfortunately it isn't my code, it is simply a library that I am needing to use. I am only porting the low level C to C# so I can get a much better idea of how the code works (since I'm not particularly familiar with low level C) so that it will help me rewrite the code in modern C#.

Comment: If this is just a library then maybe you should just create a wrapper and then use PInvoke to call C code from C#?

Comment: @csharpfolk I did try that but unfortunately couldn't get it to work. Also attempted to use C++/CLI which worked (kinda) but it turns out the C code actually only works when compiled with MinGW, the code breaks if it's compiled with MSVC so I decided I would port it over to C#.

Comment: You can use C# arrays to achieve something similar to what you get using malloc in C. `allocNodes = new Queue[Global.QUEUECHUNK]` (you must declare `allocNodes` as `Queue[]`). Then, you can return `allocNodes[lastNode++]`.

Comment: @Milack I did think of that, but I can't do `return allocNodes` as the `tmp` variable in the `createQueueNode` function expects a single Queue and not an array.

Comment: But you're not supposed to return an array. You must return `allocNodes[index]`, which is an element of it, not the array itself.

Comment: @Milack Sorry yeah I realise that, it's the line inside the else statement in the C code that I'm talking about where it has `return alloc_nodes`. It does not specify an index so I would not know what index to use.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Inside the else statement, I suppose you want to return the first element of the array, that is `allocNodes[0]`.

Comment: Ahh yeah of course that would make sense. I'll try that out and see how I get on. Thanks!